# TDD best practice?

Tags: java, tdd, mockito

Im using a TDD approach with my latest project. Its new for me :)

I have a service which will save a CSV record to the database. It will check values for existence and add if necessary - hence the multiple DAOs.

Below is a test that runs ok - but can someone please tell me if there is a better way to write this? It doesn't feel right.

Thanks

```
@Test
public void loadTest() {
    //mock....all methods called in my save method
    Dao1 dao1 = mock(Dao1.class);
    when(dao1.findByDescription(anyString())).thenReturn(mock(Model1.class));
    Dao2 dao2 = mock(Dao2.class);
    when(dao2.findByDescription(anyString())).thenReturn(mock(Model2.class));
    Dao3 dao3 = mock(Dao3.class);
    when(dao3.findByDescription(anyString())).thenReturn(mock(Model3.class));
    Dao4 dao4 = mock(Dao4.class);

    RowFromCsv row = mock(RowFromCsv.class);
    when(row.getAttribute1()).thenReturn(new DateTime()); //otherwise test fails - nullpointerexception
    when(row.getAttribute2()).thenReturn(new DateTime());
    Csv csv = mock(Csv.class);
    when(csv.next()).thenReturn(row).thenReturn(null);

    //this is what im testing...
    Service load = new Service();
    load.setDao1(dao1);
    load.setDao2(dao2);
    load.setDao3(dao3);
    load.setDao4(dao4);
    load.save(csv);

    //save called ok...
    verify(dao4).createOrUpdate(any(Model4.class));
}
```

Comment: You are mocking too much. The `Model`, `RowFromCsv`, and `Csv` classes should almost certainly *not* be mocked in this test.

Comment: Please elaborate - it does feel like I'm mocking too much. However if I don't mock these then how do I properly test my save method?

Comment: I meant that the test should use those classes unmocked. `Model1`, `RowFromCsv`, etc. look like they can simply be instantiated in test code, with the necessary values for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test looks OK. You setup your fixtures, execute the method and then verify that it did what you expected.

You could make it more readable if you created a utility class that serves as mock factory. Assuming that the method `findByDescription(string)` is defined in the class or interface `BaseDao`, you could do something like the following:

```
public class MockFactory {
    public static <D extends BaseDao,M> D mockDao(Class<D> daoClass, Class<M> modelClass) {
        D dao = mock(daoClass);
        M model = mock(modelClass);
        when(dao.findByDescription(anyString())).thenReturn(model));
        return dao;
    }

    public static Csv csvWithOneRecord() {
        RowFromCsv row = mock(RowFromCsv.class);
        when(row.getAttribute1()).thenReturn(new DateTime()); 
        when(row.getAttribute2()).thenReturn(new DateTime());
        Csv csv = mock(Csv.class);
        when(csv.next()).thenReturn(row).thenReturn(null);
    }
}
```

This approach makes your test more readable and your mocks reusable.
Just make sure that the factory methods have names that describe what kind of mocks they return. If you need a lot of suck factory methods, then you should create more than one utility classes, each utility class dedicated to one type of mock. ie `DaoMockFactory`, `CsvMockFactory` etc.

One more thing: It is a good idea to follow some naming conventions:

- Have one test class for each main class ie `class TestService` for `class Service`.
- Have the unit test method named after the method it is testing ie method `testSave()` tests method `save()`.